# How to find the byte data in pyserial readline in Python 3.x

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pyserial

How to find the substring in serial byte data that is newline terminated. I just want to extract the data from the uart stream.

Not able to find byte data in `Pyserial` line.

I can able to find imei the first line but the second line it's not able to find in several ways I tried?

EDIT:
It's a typo no escape sequence.

**Output in my UART stream:**

```
b'\xfeimei_1234567777777\n'
b'ccid_123123324234234234324\n'
```

Any help very appreciated.

Minimal code example:

```
IMEI=b'imei_'

CCID=b'ccid_'
ccid = b'ccid_123123324234234234324\n'
XFIND_CCID=b'ccid_12'
OCCID=b'12'

#Here open the serial connection
run = True
while run:
  data=device.readline()
  print(data)

  #It works for this well without any issue.
  if data.find(IMEI) == 1:
      v_imei = data
      print(imei)

  #None of the method works
  #Method 1
  if data.find(CCID) == 1:
      ccid = data
      print(ccid)

  #Method 2
  if data.find(ccid) == 1:
      v_ccid = data
      print("Hurray we found the CCID %s" % v_ccid)

  #Method 3
  if data.find(OCCID) == 1:
      v_ccid = data
      print("OCCID we found the CCID %s" % v_ccid)


  #Method 4
  if data.find(XFIND_CCID) == 1:
      print("XX Hurray we found the CCID")

  if data == "end"
      run = False
```

Comment: Are you sure `'\ccid_12'` isn't a typo? I've never seen that escape before.

Comment: What do you expect `bytes.find` to return, based on your interpretation of the docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that `bytes.find`, like `str.find`, returns the starting index of the first matching character it finds.

The first comparison works because you have `\xfe` at index 0, placing `imei` indeed at index 1.

The remaining comparisons don't work because `ccid_` is at index 0, not index 1 in the second line.

If you want a `bool` indicating whether one `bytes` appears in another, and don't really care about the index, use the `in` operator instead, e.g.:

```
 if CCID in data:
```

If you really do care about the index, you can check that `find` returns non-negative, since it returns `-1` if the item is not found:

```
if data.find(CCID) >= 0:
```

Your final option is to use exception handling. This is only really a good way if you want to work with the assumption that the CCID must be in your data and anything else is really abnormal. The `index` method is like `find`, except it raises an error instead of returning `-1`:

```
try:
    i = data.index(ccid)
    # ok, index found
except IndexError:
    # not ok
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `if data.find(CCID) >= 0:`  did the job, what I was expecting.

Comment: @danglingpointer. If you don't keep the index, I really think `in` is a much better option.